# ReadAsync throwing IOException

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a windows service that crawls thousands of web pages, I've noticed that the ReadAsync method intermittently throws IOExceptions, I've confirmed this is due to the TCP Window Size reaching 0 and the client being unable to process anymore data. Is it possible to increase the TCP window size buffer for the method? Also what approach would you recommend to overcoming the IOException? Would it be fair to say that the ReadAsync method is bad at handling multiple requests - as this is the time when the exceptions are being thrown, it can handle a few downloads but anymore than say 32 it intermittently throws exceptions. I have confirmed it is not a bandwidth, memory nor a cpu issue as I have monitored these resources and they seem not to be over utilized.

The actual exception is:

```
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.PooledStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginReadWithoutValidation(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state) 
at System.IO.StreamExtensions.ReadAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in C:\app\Extras\C#,C++,F#,VB\Extras\Extensions\APM\StreamExtensions.cs:line 29 
at App.StreamExtensions.<CopyStreamIterator>d__6.MoveNext() in c:\app\Extensions\StreamExtensions.cs:line 199 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactoryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Iterate>b__7(Task antecedent) in c:\app\Extras\C#,C++,F#,VB\Extras\Extensions\TaskFactoryExtensions\TaskFactoryExtensions_Iterate.cs:line 183
```

I've confirmed it's due to the TCP window size reaching 0 using wireshark, I can see the server sending a connection reset. I've also looked at the last request sent by the client which shows the tcp window size at zero. Basically I'm attempting to copy a stream to memory, the interesting thing is if I use the non-async CopyTo method I get no buffer overflows with hundreds of requests being made. Bearing in mind every request is running in a separate thread so the requests themselves are still parallel.

Comment: Sounds to me like the remote server shut you out. Are you scanning a bit too fast for their liking?

Comment: " I've confirmed this is due to the TCP Window Size reaching 0 and the client being unable to process anymore data" -- how did you confirm this, exactly? What is `System.IO.StreamExtensions`? Are you using an old TPL release? It may have limitations not in the official `async`-aware .NET versions. That said, the official `Stream.ReadAsync()` just delegates to `NetworkStream.BeginRead()` which in turn delegates to `Socket.BeginReceive()`, none of which I would expect to be specifically limited in that way. Sounds more like you have problems at a lower level in the network stack.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're correct System.IO.StreamExtensions is from an old TPL release. I'm specifically using "StreamExtensions.ReadAllBytesAsync" method, do you know of any method in the official async-aware versions of .NET I could use? I've also updated by question with a bit more info.

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in equivalent, no. But it's relatively trivial to write, given current `async` support. It'd be based on the same API you're already using though, so I don't think it'd address the specific issue. None of the symptoms seem really related to .NET per se. I think you might want to look more closely at other network components: firewall, router, switches, anti-virus, etc. It's not clear from your post which is "server" and which is "client", but if your crawler is the "client", it's entirely possible the server just doesn't like being crawled and is resetting on purpose.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for all your help, I'll look into your suggestions.